# SFP28 port and SFP module (not SFP+)

Tags: ethernet, sfp

I'm about to buy a device that has some SFP28 ports. I know that SFP28 is backward compatible with SFP+. But I want to know its backward compatibility with the SFP module.
Can I use an SFP module (1Gbps) with an SFP28 port in all situations? (different implementation, different vendors,....)

Answer (score 2):

There's no general rule.

Some SFP28 ports (25 Gbit/s) are backward compatible with SFP modules (1 Gbit/s), many aren't. You'll need to check the specifications for the device in question.

For reference, not all SFP28 ports are compatible with SFP+ modules (10 Gbit/s), and not all SFP+ ports are compatible with SFP modules either.